# Netbeans 8.2 How to switch from JRE to JDK?

Tags: cordova, netbeans

I have Netbeans 8.2 installed on iOS.

I am very new to Netbeans and am trying to run Cordova (android emulator) on a simple "Hello World" project.

I get the error [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyhUd.png)

Can anyone advise how to switch from JRE to JDK. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the JDK installed. This can be downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (this page includes a link to a download of Netbeans with the JDK) or the app store. When you have the JDK installed in Netbeans go to Tools -> Java Platforms. Here click the add platform button. In the add Java platform screen choose Java Standard edition and click next. Now select the folder where the JDK is installed and click next. The screen should show the details you just filled in. Now click the finish button and the JDK should be listed. YOu may need to restart Netbeans to load the JDK.

Comment: Many thanks for replying. Is that Tools-> Platforms in the Netbeans IDE? Because that option doesn't seem to appear in v8.0.

Comment: I meant Tools -> Java Platforms which does exist in 8.2. I have updated my answer with the correction.

Comment: Again thanks. It is simply not there ( not even as a faded option ) the list I have under tools -> Apply Diff Patch, Add to Favorites, Show in Finder, Open in Terminal, Create Update Tests, Ant Variables, Libraries, Servers, Cloud Providers, Templates, Palette, Plugins.